# Why function arguments induce list context?

Tags: perl

I have a function, which depends on calling context and i wanted to use this function as as argument to other function. Surprisingly i discovered that this `second` function is called in list context now. I tried force scalar context with `+()` but it does not work as i expected. So only way was to call it implicitly with `scalar`.

```
use 5.010;

say first( 1, second( 'y' ) );
say first( 1, +( second( 'y' ) ) );
say first( 1, scalar second( 'y' ) );

sub first {
  my $x = shift;
  my $y = shift;

  return "$x + $y";
}

sub second {
  my $y = shift;

  if ( wantarray ) {
    qw/ array array /;
  } else {
    'scalar';
  }
}
__END__
1 + array
1 + array
1 + scalar
```

Arguments to function are treated as list, but does it mean that every argument in that list implies list context too? If yes, then why?

And, using `scalar` works, but which other ways i have to call this function in scalar context (without intermediate variable)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why function arguments induce list context?

Subroutines accept a variable number of scalars as arguments. What other choice is there?

> Arguments to function are treated as list, but does it mean that every argument in that list implies list context too? If yes, then why?

Yes. Because you want to be able to build lists from the contents of hashes and arrays. There's a million reason why that's useful.

```
%h = (%h, ...);  # Add to a hash
f( $x, @opts );  # Composing argument lists
etc
```

> using `scalar` works, but which other ways i have to call this function in scalar context (without intermediate variable)?

Kinda.

```
say first( 1, "".second( 'y' ) );    # Side-effect: stringification
say first( 1, 0+.second( 'y' ) );    # Side-effect: numificatiion
say first( 1, !!second( 'y' ) );     # Side-effect: conversion to boolean
```

Subrountine prototypes can also enforce scalar context, but they're generally seen as bad for that very reason.

Comment: Of course, every member in list may be also list, so there is not much choices. Did not think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

It makes sense that function arguments are evaluated in list context:

- In Perl, all subroutines map lists to lists.
- If a sub takes a list, it makes sense to evaluate all arguments in list context, which makes functions *composable*. Consider `map`:

  ```
  map { ... } 1, 2, 3; # makes sense
  map { ... } foo();   # can we "return 1, 2, 3" for the same effect?
  ```

  Should the `foo()` be called in scalar context, this would be equivalent to `return 3` when we intended to return the list `1, 2, 3`. Using list context enables us to compose list transformations without to many explicit loops. The *Schwartzian Transform* is a prime example of this:

  ```
  my @sorted =
    map  { $_->[1] }
    sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map  { [make_key($_), $_] }
    @input;
  ```

There are two ways to evaluate an argument in list context:

- Use an expression that forces scalar context, like `scalar` or scalar operations.
- Use *prototypes* like `($)`. This destroys composability of functions, requires your subroutine to be predeclared, can have confusing semantics, and is *action at a distance*. Prototypes should therefore be avoided.

Your `+(...)` did not force scalar context because *unary* plus does not impose context. It is commonly used to disambiguate parens (e.g. used for precedence) from a function application, e.g. `map +($_ => 2*$_), 1, 2, 3`.

The unary plus is distinct from the binary plus, an arithmetic operator which imposes scalar context on its operands and coerces them to numbers.